# What's the max limit for messages in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

I've tried to inserting bigger images through a WCF-service and I ain't successful. It complains the sending message is too big. I've sent smaller images which went fine, but the bigger images I have more trouble with. 
I've tried (without success) altering in the web.config:

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <!-- binding configuration with a name -->
        <binding name="ExtendedMaxSize" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647000000" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

*The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.*

Maybe it ain't possible to send so big images through wcf? I don't really know so therefore I'm asking.

Comment: Are you limited to using the `basicHttpBinding`? Other bindings might have a higher limit.
- or -
How large are these images? Can you resize them down a bit before sending them?

Comment: You need to set the readerQuotas as well. The maxRecievedMEssageSize should be set  on client and server side as well. Better to have the same values for each property on client and server

Answer (score 2):

Here is MSDN article that might be useful for you: [WFC Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx).

Also, if you're using IIS 6, you might be experiencing this [issue](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/7e0d74d3-ca01-4d36-8ac7-6b2ca03fd383.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: Actually, it appears that this applies to IIS 7 (and 7.5) as well, see the following post: http://tmoaikel.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/http-413-request-entity-too-large-in-iis-6-and-7/